# Explanation for chained Matrix Multiplication using DP?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

I could not understand the optimised chained Matrix multiplication(using DP) code example given in my algorithm's book.

```
int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int n)
{

    /* For simplicity of the program, one extra row and one extra column are
       allocated in m[][].  0th row and 0th column of m[][] are not used */
    int m[n][n];

    int i, j, k, L, q;

    /* m[i,j] = Minimum number of scalar multiplications needed to compute
       the matrix A[i]A[i+1]...A[j] = A[i..j] where dimention of A[i] is
       p[i-1] x p[i] */

    // cost is zero when multiplying one matrix.
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        m[i][i] = 0;

    // L is chain length.  
    for (L=2; L<n; L++)   
    {
        for (i=1; i<=n-L+1; i++)
        {
            j = i+L-1;
            m[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            for (k=i; k<=j-1; k++)
            {
                // q = cost/scalar multiplications
                q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
                if (q < m[i][j])
                    m[i][j] = q;
            }
        }
    }

    return m[1][n-1];
}
```

Why does the first loop starts from 2 ? 
Why is j set to i+L-1 and i to n-L+1 ?

I understood the recurrence relation, but could not understand why loops are set like this ?

EDIT:

What is the way to get the parenthesis order after DP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bottom up, that is DP we try to solve the smallest possible case first(we solve each smallest case). Now when we look at the recurrence (m[i,j] represents cost to parenthise from i , j..)

[image: m[i,j] represents cost to parenthise from i , j..]

We can see that the smallest possible solution(which will be needed by any other larger sub problem) is **of a smaller length than that we need to solve**... For P(n) .We need all the costs of parenthising the expression with length lessser than n. This leads us to solve the problem lengthwise... (Note l in the outer loop represents length of the segment whose cost we are trying to optimise)

Now first we solve all the sub problems of length 1 i.e. 0 always (No multiplication required)...

Now your question L=2 -> L=n
we are varying length from 2 to n just to solve the sub problems in order...

i is the starting point of all the sub intervals such that they can be the begining of an interval of length l..

Naturally j represents the  end of sub interval -> i+l-1 is the end of sub interval (just because we know the starting point and length we can figure out the end of subinterval)

Comment: hi Shubham , how is i+L-1 not greater than n ? So this is what I understood till now, we are looping through chain of different length (say total length given was 8) , so we find optimal solutions for different combinations,ie, 2,6 |3,5|4,4 . that is the reason i goes to (n-L+1) ? Because we are dividing that original 8 , into 2 sub problems ?

Comment: See the upper limit of i i.e n-L+1 now when we add (n-L+1+L-1) i.e i+L-1 we get j=n. So no j will never exceed n.

And we are dividing M[i,j] into several subproblems and taking optimal from that ... See the  recurrence or refer (http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Dynamic/chainMatrixMult.htm)

Answer (score 1):

*L* iterates the length of a chain. Clearly, a chain cannot be 1 piece long. *i* iterates the beginning of the chain. If the first piece is *i*, then the last piece will be *i+L-1*, which is *j*. (Try to imagine a chain and count). The condition in the cycle makes sure that for any value of *i*, the last piece is not greater than the maximum Length *n*.
Shortly, those are limitations to keep the values in the given boundaries.